# React Dnd canDrop prop not turning true but isOver works fine

Tags: reactjs, react-dnd

I have 3 components in my Reactjs demo project and i am using the react **[DnD](https://react-dnd.github.io/react-dnd/)** component.

React [DnD Examples](https://react-dnd.github.io/react-dnd/examples-chessboard-tutorial-app.html) here.

Box.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { DropTarget } from 'react-dnd';


const boxTarget = {
    canDrop(props) {
        // alert()
    },

    drop(props) {
        // alert()
    }
};

function collect(connect, monitor) {
    return {
      connectDropTarget: connect.dropTarget(),
      isOver: monitor.isOver(),
      canDrop: monitor.canDrop()
    };
}

const ItemTypes = {
    CARD: 'card'
};


class Box extends Component {

    render() {
        const { connectDropTarget, isOver, canDrop } = this.props;

        return connectDropTarget(
          <div style={{
            position: 'relative',
            width: '200px',
            height: '200px',
            background: isOver ? '#ff0000' : '#eee'
          }}>
              { this.props.children }
          </div>
        );
    }

}

export default DropTarget(ItemTypes.CARD, boxTarget, collect)(Box);
```

card.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { DragSource } from 'react-dnd';


const ItemTypes = {
    CARD: 'card'
};

const cardSource = {
    beginDrag(props) {
      return {  };
    },

    endDrag(props, monitor) {
      const item = monitor.getItem()
      const dropResult = monitor.getDropResult()

      if (dropResult) {
        alert(`You dropped ${item.name} into ${dropResult.name}!`)
      }
    },
}

function collect(connect, monitor) {
    return {
       connectDragSource : connect.dragSource(),
       connectDragPreview: connect.dragPreview(),
       isDragging : monitor.isDragging()
    } 
}

class Card extends Component {

    render() {
        const { connectDragSource , isDragging } = this.props;

        return connectDragSource( 
          <div style={{
            opacity : isDragging ? 0.5 : 1,
            height: '50px',
            width: '50px',
            backgroundColor: 'orange',
          }}>
            &#9822;
          </div>
        );
      }

}

export default DragSource(ItemTypes.CARD, cardSource , collect)(Card);
```

simpleDrag.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import { DragDropContext } from 'react-dnd';
import HTML5Backend from 'react-dnd-html5-backend';
import CARD from './card';
import BOX from './box';
import Calder from './fullcalender';

class simpleDrag extends Component {

    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <BOX />
                <CARD/>
            </div>    
        ); 
    }

} 

export default DragDropContext(HTML5Backend)(simpleDrag);
```

`simpleDrag.js` is the parent component that displays both the box and card components , now the problem i face is in box.js i have the following ternary check for styling:

```
background: isOver ? '#ff0000' : '#eee'
```

Now for `isOver` this the styling works , that is the div becomes "#ff0000" , but this check somehow does't work for `canDrop` , Why does the `canDrop` check not work ?

The above code can be found in my github repo [HERE](https://github.com/gautamz07/action-snowball).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be returning true/false from **canDrop** inside **boxTarget** in **Box.js**.

Comment: Thanks buddy ! thats was of great help !

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik Sure :)